# When to use multiple then statements vs putting your code block into one then statement

Tags: javascript

I have an api call that returns the data asynchronously and I have 2 methods that then do something after that call has happened but they don't create new promises by themselves.

Does

```js
const foo = new Promise(…);

foo.then(() => {
    console.log("foo");
    console.log("bar")
})
```

Provide benefits over

```js
const foo = new Promise(…);

foo
    .then(() => console.log("foo"))
    .then(() => console.log("bar"))
```

?

I get that if the first thenable returns a promise that it's useful to chain another then statement but is chaining then statements also beneficial when the first thenable does not return a promise?

I assume more granular control over errors could be one:

```js
const foo = new Promise(…);

foo
    .then(() => throw error("Whoopsie"))
    .catch(e => handle(e))
    .then(() => throw error("Daisy"))
    .catch(e => handle(e))
```

Comment: I think a lot of it depends on whether control of sequencing is important to you :) Daisy-Whoopsie is always a weird message to get ;)

Answer (score 0):

> I get that if the first thenable returns a promise that it's useful to chain another then statement but is chaining then statements also beneficial when the first thenable does not return a promise?

What do you mean by return a promise?  A promise is always returned, with the result of the resolver called on the current value (modulo errors).

Consider this:

```
p = new Promise( r => r('foo'));
p.then((val) => {console.log(val); return val + 'bar'})
 .then(console.log)
 .then(console.log);
/* output:
foo
foobar
undefined
*/
```

1. Using `r`, the promise "gets the chain going" by calling it on the value computed by whatever the function in the constructor of the promise returns
2. after that the next callback is called on that value, which returns `'foo' + 'bar'`
3. then `console.log` is passed in, which doesn't return anything (i.e. returns `undefined`)
4. finally `console.log` is called on `undefined`

A promise is always returned, which is why `then` can be called over and over again.  Whether or not to chain `then` calls vs putting your entire function into one big callback is more a question of whether or not you would like your function to be able to be "interrupted" or not in the middle of computation.